# list is editing all values instead of just one

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
snake = []
snake_size = 10
snake.append([display_width / 2, display_height / 2])
snake_dx = 10
snake_dy = 0  

#I then declare some more lists in snake in an identical fashion

for i in range(len(snake) - 1, 0, -1):
    snake[i] = snake[i - 1]

try:
    print('1', snake[1])
except:
    pass
snake[0][0] += snake_dx
snake[0][1] += snake_dy
try:
    print('2', snake[1])
except:
    pass
```

This will print, for example:
1 (100, 100)
2 (110, 100)

Could somebody please explain to me why this value is changing and how I can prevent it?
Thank you!

Comment: Please edit to post the initialization of the variable `snake`. I suspect you're inserting the same object twice.

Comment: I added some more code if that helps

Comment: recommended reading: **[Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is the line:

```
snake[i] = snake[i - 1]
```

This assigns `snake[1]` as the same *object* as `snake[0]`, not to a copy of the object with the same *contents*.

To make a copy of the object, use `snake[i - 1][:]` or `list(snake[i - 1])`.

---

You should probably spend some time thinking about object identity, since it is a critically important part of mutable objects in python. In other words, play around with an interactive shell and the `id` function.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of what @o11 wrote, you could use tuples for your (x,y) pairs instead of lists. Tuples are immutable, so can use and assign them without the risk of getting unwanted side effects, which is much less error prone. This will lead to code like

```
 snake.append((display_width / 2, display_height / 2))
```

Now you cannot write

```
 snake[0][0] += snake_dx
 snake[0][1] += snake_dy
```

any more (this would give you a runtime error). Instead, you have to replace those two lines by

```
 snake[0] = (snake[0][0] + snake_dx, snake[0][1] + snake_dy)
```

The line

```
 snake[i] = snake[i - 1]
```

does not have to be modified.